# Simplification of integral with division between summations

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, summation, integral-inequality

Considering that

$$\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} \int f_j(x) < \infty$$ and $$\sum_{j = 0}^{\infty} \int g_j(x) < \infty$$, $\forall x \in \mathrm{R} : f(x) \gt 0, g(x) \gt 0$. How can I simplify the following expression ?

$$ \int \frac{\sum_{j = n}^N f_j(x)}{\sum_{j = n}^N g_j(x)} dx $$

Comment: I voted to reopen. I think your edit was substantial. ;-) Hopefully, others will do likewise. Hang in there!

Comment: Now one can answer... Q: *how can I simplify the following expression?* A: you can't (and Beppo-Levi is unrelated).

Comment: There is no hyphen in «Beppo-Levi»: Beppo is the first name of the guy and Levi is his last name! What does Beppo Levi have to do with this question, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I simplify the following expression ? $$\int \frac{\sum_{j = n}^N f_j(x)}{\sum_{j = n}^N g_j(x)} dx$$

You cannot, without some assumptions that relate $f_j$ to $g_j$. (Or, what Did said in a comment.)

Comment: I hope that this valuable answer justifies the effort that went into reopening the question.